# How do I check the similarities of two unequal length sub-lists and add to the score of list 2 when there is a match from list 1?

Tags: python

I have 2 sublists that I need to check for similarities and keep an account of how many matches were produced even if there is a single match. Any help will be greatly appreciated!

INPUT

```
list_1 = [[a,b,c],[d,e,g],[l,r],[z]]

list_2 = [[b,c], [l,e,a], [f], [z,r]]
```

OUTPUT

Similarities:

```
list_2[0] : list_1[0]

list_2[1] : list_1[0], list_1[1], list_1[2]

list_2[2] : none

list_2[3] : list_1[2], list_1[3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list_1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','g'],['l','r'],['z']]

list_2 = [['b','c'], ['l','e','a'], ['f'], ['z','r']]

for i in range(len(list_1)):
    for j in range(len(list_2)):
        if set(list_2[j]) & set(list_1[i]):
            print('list_1[{}], list_2[{}]'.format(i, j), 'matching value:',set(list_2[j]) & set(list_1[i]))
        else:
            print('list_1[{}], list_2[{}]'.format(i, j), 'None')
```

## output

```
# list_1[0], list_2[0] matching value: {'b', 'c'}
# list_1[0], list_2[1] matching value: {'a'}
# list_1[0], list_2[2] None
# list_1[0], list_2[3] None
# list_1[1], list_2[0] None
# list_1[1], list_2[1] matching value: {'e'}
# list_1[1], list_2[2] None
# list_1[1], list_2[3] None
# list_1[2], list_2[0] None
# list_1[2], list_2[1] matching value: {'l'}
# list_1[2], list_2[2] None
# list_1[2], list_2[3] matching value: {'r'}
# list_1[3], list_2[0] None
# list_1[3], list_2[1] None
# list_1[3], list_2[2] None
# list_1[3], list_2[3] matching value: {'z'}
```

You can use the set() function and & to check if there are some matching value in two lists. And use two for loop to look through all the values of these two lists.

Comment: set operation is too costly

Comment: Thank you! This works for me! Just to point out that there is an extra `')` on the last print statement. But the rest works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

adding the index where list_2 values present in list_1,

here [] in output means None

```
list_1 = [['a','b','c'],['d','e','g'],['l','r'],['z']]
list_2 = [['b','c'], ['l','e','a'], ['f'], ['z','r']]
from collections import defaultdict

dic = defaultdict(list)

for i in range(len(list_1)):
    for j in list_1[i]:
        dic[j]+=[i]
output=[]
for i in list_2:
    tmp=[]
    for j in i:
        tmp.append(dic[j])
    output.append(tmp)
print(list2,output,sep='\n')
"""
  output

list_2 = [['b','c'], ['l','e','a'], ['f'], ['z','r']]
output =  [[[0], [0]], [[2], [1], [0]], [[]], [[3], [2]]]

"""
```